# Ignore "the" php / mysql output

Tags: php, mysql

I sort my data in alphabetical order, although the entries that begin with "the" i wish to ignore sorting by the first word and make it sort by the second word instead.

For example "The View" would be listed under V and not T,  Whats the best way to do this?

I know there's a simple little thing i can do as i use to do it back in the day but can't for the life of me remember. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a resultset from MySQL in the order you specified, you can use:

```
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM entry)
```

This will remove multiple occurrences, so e.g. 'The The Now' would be returned as 'Now'.
Also, it's only going to pull off the single space following the word 'The'.

And this may be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use your own compare function, so that php takes the second word if the index starts with "The":

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    $a = preg_replace("/^the /i","",$a);
    $b = preg_replace("/^the /i","",$b);
    return strcmp($a,$b);
}
```

and the sorting:

```
$array = array("The Vektor", "Apple", "The Anchor", "Bee");
usort($array, 'cmp');
print_r($array);
```

i think this should work.. ;) .. and in Addition, it does not remove "The" from the text, because the compared variables are just local :)

the output:

```
Array ( [0] => The Anchor [1] => Apple [2] => Bee [3] => The Vektor )
```

Comment: I think you want to include a space in that regular expression. Without it, won't an entry like e.g. 'Themes and Compositions' going to get compared as 'mes and Compositions'?

Comment: You are right ;) --> corrected it.. and i can leave away the trim then :P